# Saving a Word document to Sharepoint

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, sharepoint, integration

When I create a Word document, I have to option to save it to our installation of Sharepoint by going to the **File** tab, the **Save and Send | Save to SharePoint**. 
I’m looking for a way to a.) add “**Save to SharePoint**” to my quick access bar, b .) add it to the **file** tab (skipping the “save and send” click), or c.) assign a key command via a macro.

I've been terribly unsuccessful. Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can have a  Group policy in our domain that Set it for ALL !!! :

1. by enabling folder redirection you can save all WORD files like previous in your desktop or Documents.
2. another work is when to go config Folder redirection , replace the URL of sharepoint instead of FQDN that it wants

for example , you have SharePoint Document Library like this: `http://servername/sitename/DocLib1`

- by replaacing "\\" with "http://" and replace "\" with "/" : for example if `http://servername/sitename/DocLib1`  you are type : \\servername\sitename\DocLib1